# Getting "Access token validation failure. Invalid audience" for Aad application in spfx

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

I have created one AAD application with below configuration and trying to access the Graph APIs added in the AAD application using SPFx

[image]

[image: 1]

[image]

[image]

SPFx configuration and code:

[image]

[image]

Error:

[image]

Please suggest if I am missing any step? or Do I need to use MSAL in SPFx to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the scope is right.You could take a reference to this blog to call Graph API in SPFX.

[Create SPFx web part to get user details using Graph API](https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/sharepoint-spfx-graph-api/)

And official demo:

[Use the MSGraphClient to connect to Microsoft Graph](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-msgraph)

Comment: Yes I can make call to Graph API similar to blog post. but my ultimate goal is to call MS Flow related functionality and to API to access all the site collections with the help of   AAD application and I am first trying to access Graph API using AAd Application just to see how the API calls will work using AAD application. Also scope name can be anything while creating AAD application. IMO.